# ERROR: undefined method `aws_access_key' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to use AWS S3 bucket in below recipe for remote file, So that 
whenever someone change in **/tmp/fileA.txt**. chef client will run the below code and replace the **fileA** with original **file_Source.txt** from AWS S3 bucket.

```
remote_file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
    source 'https://awsS3bucketname/file_Source.txt'
    aws_access_key "mykey"
    aws_secret_key  "mykey"
    action :create
end
```

but i am getting **ERROR: undefined method `aws_access_key'** when i am running above code.

```
 [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
   Running handlers complete
   [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
   Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds
   [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
   [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
   [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] ERROR: undefined method `aws_access_key' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile
   [2018-06-20T07:04:25-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remote_file` doesn't include support for getting files from S3. You should look at the [`aws`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws) cookbook which includes an s3 file resource:

> `s3_file` can be used to download a file from s3 that requires aws
>   authorization. This is a wrapper around the core chef `remote_file`
>   resource and supports the same resource attributes as `remote_file`. See
>   `remote_file` Chef Docs for a complete list of available attributes.

In addition it adds properties to handle authorization to S3:

> ### Properties:
>
> `aws_secret_access_key`, `aws_access_key` and optionally
>   `aws_session_token` - required, unless using IAM roles for
>   authentication.
>   `region` - The AWS region containing the file. Default:
>   The current region of the node when running in AWS or us-east-1 if the
>   node is not in AWS.

#### Example:

```
aws_s3_file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
    bucket 'yourbucket'
    remote_path 'file_Source.txt'
    aws_access_key 'mykey'
    aws_secret_access_key 'mykey'
    region 'us-east-1'
    action :create
end
```

**EDIT:**

You can set this as a dependency inside your `metadata.rb` file in your cookbook, like this:

```
depends 'aws'
```

This will give you access to the custom resources inside this cookbook.

Comment: ERROR: No resource or method named `aws_s3_file'

Comment: Did you add that cookbook as a dependency?

Comment: dependency means? there is number of recipes inside my cookbook and i am running all these recipes with default.rb by passing all recipes name.

Comment: yesi have added depend in metadata.rb but still there is a issue with ERROR: undefined method `aws_secret_key' for Custom resource aws_s3_file from cookbook aws

Comment: Sorry @PawanSharma see the corrected answer it should be `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_access_key`